# How to customise UINavigationItem title color in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a custom view controller from present which i tried to add a nav bar. This is the code i used for it.

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
let startingYPos = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0

let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: startingYPos, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 44))
navBar.barTintColor = UIColor(named: "backgroundColor")
navBar.isTranslucent = false
navBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "App Name")

let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.cancel, target: nil, action: #selector(cancelAction))
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: true)

self.view.addSubview(navBar)
```

The question is, is there a way to change the colour of the title? Currently it's black by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setup the `titleTextAttributes` will solve your problem:

```swift
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
let startingYPos = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
let navTintColor: UIColor = .white

let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "App Name")
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction))

let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: startingYPos, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44))
navBar.barTintColor = UIColor(named: "backgroundColor")
navBar.isTranslucent = false
navBar.tintColor = navTintColor
navBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: navTintColor]
navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: true)

view.addSubview(navBar)
```

Comment: Work flawlessly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
var label = UILabel()
label.text = "Text"
label.textColor = .red

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
```

Use `UIBarButtonItem(customView: )` function and set a `UILabel` with your desired color.

Or

if you don't want to `customView` init so you can set `textAttributes` for `UINavigationBar` like below.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yourColor]
```